# Flex 4.6 mobile sqlite specific data

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, mobile

First off I am new to using Flex, but I have pieced this app together with help from online tutorials and information. Basically my app is like a directory of names, addresses and so forth, but I also have additional fields of "week" and "day". What I am trying to do is have a list that shows only the names of, for example Week 1 - Monday. Below is some of the code I am using to help you understand what I am trying to do. I appreciate any help!

```
<s:List dataProvider="{AddDoctorDatabase.doctors()}" labelField="name" change="onDoctorSelected(event)"
        left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
</s:List>


public static function doctors():ArrayCollection
    {
        var doctorList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        var sql:String = "SELECT id, week, day, name, address, city, state, zip, phone FROM doctors";
        var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
        stmt.text = sql;
        stmt.execute();
        var sqlResult:SQLResult = stmt.getResult();
        if (sqlResult) {
            var result:Array = sqlResult.data;
            if (result) {
                for (var index:Number = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                    doctorList.addItem(processRow(result[index]));
                }
            }
        }
        return doctorList;
    }
```

**Adding a doctor**

```
<s:SpinnerListContainer>
        <s:SpinnerList id="weekField" width="100" height="75" labelField="week">
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object week="Week 1"/>
                <fx:Object week="Week 2"/>
            </s:ArrayList>                        
        </s:SpinnerList>
    </s:SpinnerListContainer>

    <s:Label text="Select a day:"/>
    <s:SpinnerListContainer>
        <s:SpinnerList id="dayField" width="100" height="150" labelField="day">
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object day="Monday"/>
                <fx:Object day="Tuesday"/>
                <fx:Object day="Wednesday"/>
                <fx:Object day="Thursday"/>
                <fx:Object day="Friday"/>
            </s:ArrayList>                        
        </s:SpinnerList>
    </s:SpinnerListContainer>

protected function onSave():void {
            var newDoctor:AddDoctor = new AddDoctor();
            newDoctor.week = weekField.selectedItem;
            newDoctor.day = dayField.selectedItem;
            newDoctor.name = nameField.text;
            newDoctor.address = addressField.text;
            newDoctor.city = cityField.text;
            newDoctor.state = stateField.text;
            newDoctor.zip = zipField.text;
            newDoctor.phone = phoneField.text;
            AddDoctorDatabase.addDoctor(newDoctor);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, if I do what you need is the labelFunction on the s:List instead of using a labelField, so you can conjoin the field you want for display, the function should take a item:Object parameter which will be typed as one of the data elements of your dataprovider and it should return a :String like... function myLabelFunction(item:Object):String, in the function you would do something like return item.weekValue + " - " + item.dayValue

Comment: Basically the sqlite database has id, week, name, address, city, state, zip, phone. I want to be able to populate a list which shows the names for a specific week and a specific day. For example, show all the names for Week 1 on Tuesday.

Comment: okay 2 questions before I think I can give you an answer. 1 what is processRow? 2 do you have other input boxes where you select the week and the day and you want it to give you rows that only match that week and day?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what processRow is, it is something I saw in a tutorial and used it. As for the 2nd question, yes I have two SpinnerLists that allows the user to select "Week 1" or "Week 2" for the week field and then "Monday...Friday" for the day fields. I have added the code to my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is inspired by [Christophe Coenraets](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/author_bios/christophe_coenraets.html)'s [employee directory sample](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/employee-directory-android-flex.htmlo), you'd have to create a Doctor Class and set its public variable in the processRow function with your retrieved data before adding the newly created Doctor object in the ArrayCollection:

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   //Add this
   [Bindable]
   public var dList:ArrayCollection;



private function searchDoctorsClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dList = getDoctorForWeekAndDay(weekField.selectedItem, dayField.selectedItem);
}

private function creationComplete_handler(event:Event):void
{
    dList = getAllDoctors();
}

public function getAllDoctors():ArrayCollection
{
    var doctorList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    var sql:String = "SELECT id, week, day, name, address, city, state, zip, phone FROM doctors";
    var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
    stmt.text = sql;
    stmt.execute();
    var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
    if (result)
    {
       for (var index:Number = 0; index < result.length; index++)
       {
        //doctorList.addItem(processRow(result[index]));
        doctorList.addItem({result[index].week, result[index].day, result[index].name});
       }
       return doctorList;
    }
  else
  { 
     return null;
  }
}
public function processRow(o:Object):Doctor
{
    var d:Doctor = new Doctor();
    d.Name = o.name;
    d.week = o.week;
    d.day  = o.day;

    return d;
}
public class Doctor()
{
    public function Doctor(){}
    public var name:String;
    public var week:String;
    public var day:int;
}

//Call this one when they select a week and day and hit a button, or just
//on change of those options pass through the value/selectedItem from each list
public function getDoctorForWeekAndDay(chosenWeek:String, chosenDay:String):ArrayCollection
{
    var doctorList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    var sql:String = "SELECT id, week, day, name, address, city, state, zip, phone FROM doctors WHERE week='"+chosenWeek+"' AND day='"+chosenDay+"'";
    var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
    stmt.text = sql;
    stmt.execute();
    var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
    if (result)
    {
       for (var index:Number = 0; index < result.length; index++)
       {
        doctorList.addItem(processRow(result[index]));
       }
       return doctorList;
    }
  else
  { 
     return null;
  }
}
]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:List dataProvider="{dList}" change="onDoctorSelected(event)" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
  <s:IconItemRenderer label="{week} - { day }" messageField="name" />
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I think 
I'm not an expert, but i think than this could help you!

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   //Add this
   [Bindable]
   public var dList:ArrayCollection;

private function searchDoctorsClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    dList = getDoctorForWeekAndDay(weekField.selectedItem, dayField.selectedItem);
}

private function creationComplete_handler(event:Event):void
{
    dList = getAllDoctors();
}

public function getAllDoctors():ArrayCollection
{
    var doctorList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    var sql:String = "SELECT id, week, day, name, address, city, state, zip, phone FROM doctors";
    var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
    stmt.text = sql;
    stmt.execute();
    var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
    if (result)
    {
       for (var index:Number = 0; index < result.length; index++)
       {
        //doctorList.addItem(processRow(result[index]));
        doctorList.addItem({result[index].week, result[index].day, result[index].name});
       }
       return doctorList;
    }
  else
  { 
     return null;
  }
}


//Call this one when they select a week and day and hit a button, or just
//on change of those options pass through the value/selectedItem from each list
public function getDoctorForWeekAndDay(chosenWeek:String, chosenDay:String):ArrayCollection
{
    var doctorList:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

    var sql:String = "SELECT id, week, day, name, address, city, state, zip, phone FROM doctors WHERE week='"+chosenWeek+"' AND day='"+chosenDay+"'";
    var stmt:SQLStatement = new SQLStatement();
    stmt.sqlConnection = sqlConnection;
    stmt.text = sql;
    stmt.execute();
    var result:Array = stmt.getResult().data;
    if (result)
    {
       for (var index:Number = 0; index < result.length; index++)
       {
        //doctorList.addItem(processRow(result[index]));
        doctorList.addItem({result[index].week, result[index].day, result[index].name});
       }
       return doctorList;
    }
  else
  { 
     return null;
  }
}
]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:List dataProvider="{dList}" change="onDoctorSelected(event)" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
  <s:IconItemRenderer label="{week} - { day }" messageField="name" />
</s:List>
```

Comment: I think this will work, but I am getting an error 1137: Incorrect number of arguments, expected no more than 1 for the following line       doctorList.addItem(result[index].week, result[index].day, result[index].name);

Comment: I am also getting an error when I switch to design mode of the list view, I've never seen this before, but I can't see any of the design. It just says "cannot specify a value for the default property dataprovider if that property is also explicitly set as a tag or attribute."

Comment: you have to initialize the dList variable on other part of the code, try doing this 'dList=doctors()' in another function, not in the dataProvider (dataProvider="{dList}")

Comment: and, the processRow function is for an Flex example, right? this function take the array and process it to an Object, the example uses objects, I did not use the function, but if you want, see the code to modify it =)

Comment: @jclandero23 I think you got it about half-way right I'm going to try and edit your post above to get it more in line with reality but I think the original post should explain more generally what every class is that's involved in the problem as the naming of the classes is causing me a lot of confusion.  In your post you didn't update based on your comment so I'll fix that stuff, also you were missing {} within the addItem, otherwise I think more SQL just needs to be run to get them based on the selected week/day, but without a diagram/wireframe I don't know exactly what's desired.

Comment: @shaunhusain I tried something similar to what you have added above, but the one thing I keep on getting stuck on is the list function. I have tried this...<s:List dataProvider="{AddDoctorDatabase.doctors("Week 1", "Tuesday")}" labelField="name" change="onDoctorSelected(event)"
   left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"></s:List>

Comment: I just can't figure out the correct syntax of how to specify the week and day between the parenthesis. I've used quotations and colons and every possible combination, but it isn't right.

Comment: @Nik oh you probably just need to escape the " like \" or use a single quote '

Comment: @shaunhusain, don't worry, thanks for the edit, that was just an example, thanks!